# what isCOMCLASS attribute and how is used

Tags: asp.net

I was checking some code , I found comClass attribute.

what is that and what is it used for?

is there any good articles about that?

Thanks

Comment: A simple google search for the terms "comClass attribute" yeild a number of blog posts and msdn blogs on the subject.

Comment: is it simple to find?BTW have u tried? because i did and i couldn't get anything, i am not the type who dont do the research first!!

Comment: The attribute seems pretty straightforward to me. Could you please add an example of its usage that you find puzzling?

Comment: Performing a simple google search lead me to this post.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy to find, yeah...  https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS384US384&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ComClassAttribute

First link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.comclassattribute.aspx

Fifth link: http://mikedimmick.blogspot.com/2005/09/what-does-vbnet-comclass-attribute-do.html

Comment: I opened all links in google search, but couldnt find why i should use that instead of normal COM+

Comment: Bart, it's just a matter of which language you would rather write COM components in - VB or C#. If you want to use C#, you must use attributes to indicate what is exported and component GUIDs. If you use VB, you can write 'normal' COM+ code.

Comment: Currently this post is the 4th link.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be relevant only to VB (as in, it's not relevant to C#, for example). See this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.comclassattribute.aspx

Also, I thought this was a good read: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2007/06/01/so-what-does-lt-comclass-gt-actually-do.aspx; it basically says this is how you'd make a VB.NET class visible to VB6.

Other related threads that I found:

[Will VB.NET automatically generate ComClass attribute and guids?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794942/will-vb-net-automatically-generate-comclass-attribute-and-guids)

http://mikedimmick.blogspot.com/2005/09/what-does-vbnet-comclass-attribute-do.html